# How can i login to Salesforce that has Multi Factor Authentication on API calls?

Tags: c#, salesforce, multi-factor-authentication

I have started using MFA in Salesforce. I can successfully configure the setting "Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins" and use the Salesforce Authenticator app.

I have now enabled "Multi-Factor Authentication for API Logins", but in my C# app , the user enters Username, Password and Security Token and

I login to Salesforce via the following code:

```
   SFService = new SalesForceEnterpriseService.SforceService() { Timeout = 80000, Url = 
        "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/52.0"};                               
   LoginResult  result = SFService.login(Username, Password + Token);
```

But now i get the error:

```
 INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

But i assume it is due to the MFA.

How can i now login a user if MFA is enabled in API logins and will i be able to make other API calls like getting Entity fields ?

Comment: `in fact it is due to the MFA` how can you confirm this? Doesn't salseforce API documentation has any information about how to MFA in API logins after you enable it?

Comment: because i can successfully login when it is not checked and then when i check i get the error.. i will change the post to say "I assume it is due to the MFA"

Comment: I couldnt find information about this in the documentation. Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Do you pass `Token` when MFA is not enabled? How do you get the value of  `Token` ? What happens if you don't pass the `Token` when MFA is enabled?

Comment: The token you get from the Salesforce UI, it gets emailed to you. If I  pass the token when MFA  is not enabled and I can successfully login.   When MFA is not enabled and i dont pass the token , i get the following error "LOGIN_MUST_USE_SECURITY_TOKEN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out."

Comment: Surely there must be some info on this from Salesforce !

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not MFA. Go to [FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352937&type=1), search for "API" and it clearly says MFA is not required.

Do you use normal Salesforce username and password or do you have Single Sign On enabled? API logins need SF credentials (or you can use an OAuth2 flow where human sees the SSO login page, types passwords there and then is taken back to your app. Entering SSO password directly to your app & logging in with SOAP won't work)

Go to your user's login history and view most recently used IP (and/or go to whatismyip.com). Go to Setup -> Network Access and add that IP to trusted ranges. This will mean you don't need security token anymore. Check if just username and password works better, maybe there were typos or it's an old token.

Comment: if MFA is not required for API Logins,  then what and how is it used for ? Just to get a clearer understanding.

Comment: For situations where human actually sees the login screen. You have login via SOAP API, there are few REST API Oauth2 flows that don't have human element, 2 systems talking to each other. There's no way to do the MFA challenge in these.
There are ways to use MFA with APIs, for example in Data Loader you can either type the password into the app or display the login window popup - the latter will include your SSO (if there's any), your MFA... but it's optional. Ideally integration users would be even marked as "API Only" in profile so there's no way for them to get past the login screen

Comment: There are situations where you must display the login screen, for example if you have a customer/portal community. Another app can log in on this user's behalf to Salesforce, pull some data - but you won't be able to use this SOAP-related code for this, it will have to be OAuth2 flow where user sees the login screen, enters the password to SF (app doesn't see the password at any stage) and then gets redirected back to app. It's a huge topic

Comment: But if MFA API logins is enabled  and my Web app is trying to login , then that is using API login. Hence it will pass a code to the Authenticator and i must use that instead of the token specified (which doesnt rest unless by the user). So in my situation I make a number of logins to salesforce , which means that every time i lgin to Salesforce using my app via the browser  i need to specify the new code by the authenticator . That doesnt seem feasible to do. Then how can i control this ?

Comment: The code you posted logs in via SOAP. There's no "room" for MFA there, just username + password + optionally security token from email. It's good for situations when you want to have 1 integration user and store credentials in your app.
If you have web that uses REST with OAuth2 (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US&type=5 or user agent flow) - human will see SF login screen, MFA and then back to your app. If you app asked for "refresh token" scope you'll receive something extra on top of session id.

Comment: and you'll be able to use refresh token to log the user again next time silently, without login screen and MFA. Do you use sfdx/vscode or have sf developer that does? How do you think it works that developer authorises sandbox/production just once and then it works for days and days

Comment: Yes the code is SOAP. Each user logs in via the email and password and they have a token in SF that they use attached to the password.  If for any reason the token changes when they try to login , it will give an error that the password is incorrect or expired, so they must reset the token via SF UI , retrieve from the email sent to them and try again. Thats how the app is implemented. I can understand what you mean by using REST and OAuth2, + refresh token, that seems a better approach , time to implement  REST by the looks of it ,as  it doesnt look like i can use SOAP and  MFA API Logins ?

Comment: Your users should automatically receive email with new token every time they change their password. Make them mark SF as safe sender or sth so it doesn't land in junk folder? And if your users log in from office or VPN you can add their IPs to Setup -> Network Access. They won't need to append the security token to password anymore.

Comment: ok great , in reading the documentation for Salesforce it says "That’s why, beginning February 1, 2022, Salesforce will require customers to use MFA in order to access Salesforce products." , but i cant see any option for API logins as being mandatory ?

Comment: Because. It's. Not. 1st sentence in my answer. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&id=000352937 search "API". "To enable MFA for integration users, assign the Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins permission. Note that this permission applies only if someone logs in to the user account via the UI – REST or SOAP API calls aren’t affected."

Comment: yes  i can appreciate that and have seen that , but what if a client turns on API Logins ? Then my web app wont work to log the user in and throughout the app where i login to salesforce , it wont login , hope im explaining what i mean clearly .